# How can I get the IFormCollection by key the alone?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Let's say I have:

```xml
<form method="post" action="/user/create">
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" placeholder="FirstName" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I want to access my input value `FirstName` in my action method.

```cs
public IActionResult Create(IFormCollection form)
{
    string FirstName = form.Keys["FirstName"];
    return View();
}
```

It gives the error:

> ```
> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expresion of type ICollection <string>
> ```

I know I can iterate or use an `if` statement but I found that takes so much code. I just started learning C# but in Node.js and Python its so easy to get form post values, for example in Node.js:

```js
request.body.FirstName;
```

That's it. I'm looking for something similar without that iteration or creating a poco class.

Comment: Can you not use: form.Item["FirstName"]

Comment: item is not a method of form.

Comment: I suggest you to use a debug tool

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Simple Answer

You can use `form["FirstName"]` or `form.Get("FirstName")`.

---

***edit*: *You mentioned, you do not want to create a poco.
But still, consider that if you have multiple parameters:***

*Original Content:*

I'd prefer creating a class (like person, which has a FirstName Property) and use the advantage of builtin serialization.

If your Form-Parameters look like this:

```
{
  "FirstName": "John",
  "LastName": "Doe"
}
```

Then your class should be:

```
public class Person 
{
  public string FirstName {get;set;}
  public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

And your Create Method should be like this

```
public IActionResult Create([FromForm]Person p)
{
    var firstName = p.FirstName;
}
```

It will automatically parse the form parameters in to your Person object.

What a clean way reading form params, isn't it ;-)?

Comment: Not a great way if the Controller method is setup to handle unknown forms. Therefore you cannot model on the unknown.

Comment: Yes, but it was the answer of the ops question. Have a look at my previous answer which should be prefered in most cases.

Comment: I greatly appreciate the clean way to read form params.. ([FromForm]Person p). I have immediately incorporated it in my solution and it *works*. Many thanks for introducing this way to read the form.

Answer (score -3):

according to the [.NET API Catalog.](https://apisof.net/catalog/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormCollection.Item(String))
you can use

`form["FirstName"]` or
`form.item["FirstName"]`

to access the index value with iteration.

Comment: item is not a method of form.